# AWS Lambda Function Exiting Execution Improperly

Tags: tensorflow, aws-lambda

I have Lambda function trying to run PoseNet from TensorflowJS. The program executed properly until it gets to

```
    const net = await posenet.load({
      architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
      inputResolution: { width: 183, height: 275 },
      scale: 0.8,
    })
```

after this line I have a function `detect(net, image)` which internally takes the input image and executes `const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(image)` which should simply return a JSON object containing the result from the model. However, the program skips over this `detect()` function and completes the Lambda execution successfully. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

detect is async so you have to `await detect(....)`

or use then

```
detect(img).then(predictions => {
      console.log('Predictions: ', predictions);
    });
```

Comment: I believe the problem lies in the posenet.load() bit